# How to secure Admin Panel in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, admin

I have a website which has two panels....

1- For Normal user accessible through `domain.com`
2- For Admins and Moderators accessible through `admin.domain.com`

When I (or anyone) access admin panel using `admin.domain.com`. He will be asked to enter username and password...**BUT**

How can I make this only visible to me (any way of telling server.. hey I am admin show me that page)
One approach came in my mind is to use the route filter for static ips, like hey

**Laravel** my name is `192.116.45.15`... show me that page.

Another approach is to separate my whole admin from server and use it directly from my localhost.

Please tell some more approaches (by the way I use Laravel)

Comment: Your question is a little bit broad... so it's difficult to answer it directly. But you could try an iptables firewall to block all traffic to a given request but from one host.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than, doing any server configurations, why don't you use a security field.
Say, along with Username and Password, can you please add a field `PIN` to the form.
Anyways, this field is again known to you only.
Also, you can use strong passwords to protect your admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

If your approach is want the server differentiate before they login. You can set the admin page only able to accessible by admin user with (IP address).

If they had login from main page. You can get the user role session.

```
Role Level
1    Admin
2    Moderator
3    Member
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want users to see the admin login page at all you could require special GET parameter that pretty much is a password. e.g. `admin.domain.com/` would simply output nothing but `admin.domain.com/?5q38cZxyaA` would output the login page. As long as you dont publish the link anywhere this is as save as sending a password via post(so its as save as the following real login).

Comment: Security by obscurity is the laughing butt of the security crowd. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: This is why i wrote to do this only before the REAL login ! This is just meant to be enough to keep normal users away ! Moreover this has nothing to do with STO because you dont keep the algorithmen you keep the password hidden ! Where's the difference in security between transmitting a password as GET or as POST ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to the server, you can run the administration panel on some different port say port 3000 and then block that port in firewall with a exception of your own ip.

Comment: whenever you connect to internet, your ISP gives you an IP and in most cases it won't change. So once you give that ip to the filter table of firewall, you are good to go.

Comment: But when the IP *does* change?

Comment: I didn't ask when. I was asking what would be done in that case, given that you're doing IP filtering.

Comment: you can add your current ip with ssh in that case. And this is how ssh key based authentication works! I do agree that it limits you to your own ip but thats fine as far as the question goes!

Comment: One IP from the server's point of view does not mean one user. What about NAT? One external IP can mean dozens upon dozens of users. From the security standpoint, you're suggesting something like half-factor authentication, completely unacceptable and very dangerous.

Comment: @PawelJ.Wal Have you read the question properly? Asker just wants to limit the access of a page to just one IP. Now if that ip is masked behind NAT or something, thats a separate story. Moreover, solution to that can be to use Public/Private keys accompanied by some proper chain rules in firewall !!

Comment: -1 Still an extremely poor idea. You've really not answered the question with an answer that is even remotely secure.

Comment: @beNerd Cryptography and networking are two of my passions, thank you. If you downvoted my post due to my downvotes, it's somewhat rude.

Comment: @hexafraction I suggest you to pour some knowledge in your passion :) Lets end it here. Peace.